# Adding Grouped Count to Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following fields (obviously a simplified version of the actual domain)

```
MyEntity.ID,
MyEntity.Title,
MyEntity.ParentID,
MyEntity.RootID,
MyEntity.IsOpen
```

If an entity that has no parent spawns a child the ParentID is set as the ID of the parent entity and the RootID is set as the same. If that child then spawns a child then its child's parentID is it's direct parent's ID, but the Root is the ID of the eldest descendent, so:

```
ID     Title     ParentID     RootID    IsOpen
1      One       NULL         NULL      True
2      Two       1            1         False
3      Three     2            1         True
4      Four      NULL         NULL      True
```

I want a query that will return the ID and Title of each entity, plus a Boolean that is True IF the entity is open AND there are any other Open entities that are related.

So For the above table Id expect to see

```
ID     Title    IsOpenAndHasHasOpenRelations
1      One      True
2      Two      False
3      Three    True
4      Four     False
```

The IsOpenAndHasHasOpenRelations column could equally just be a count of the number of open relations

The logic is basically - Assuming entity is open, does it have a parent? If not then are there any open entities that are its children? If it does have a parent are there any open entities that share to the same root?

I'm struggling to do this as a Linq to Entities Expression though. Can anyone help?

Edit. Here is the (slightly modified) current SQL that I'm attempting to move to LINQ:

```
WITH PageIndex AS (
SELECT *
FROM EntityTable) 
SELECT 
[PageIndex].*   
,CAST (CASE 
    WHEN EntityRecord.IsOpen = THEN 0
    WHEN EntityRecord.[RootID] IS NOT NULL THEN
        CASE
        WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM EntityTable AS rootEntity
            WHERE rootEntity.[ID] = PageIndex.[RootID]
            AND (rootEntity.IsOpen = 1)
            ) > 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ELSE
        CASE
        WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EntityTable AS upissue
            WHERE upissue.RootID = PageIndex.[ID]
            AND (upissue.IsOpen = 1)
            ) > 0 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
END AS BIT) AS IsMultipleLinkexEntitiesOpen
FROM PageIndex
```

Comment: and can you show how you will do this logic in SQL?

Comment: Added SQL to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact same logic in LinQ here:

```
var res = DBcontext.EntityTable.Select(x => new
                {
                    ID = x.ID,
                    Title = x.Title,
                    IsOpenAndHasHasOpenRelations = x.IsOpen ? false
                    : x.RootID != null ? DBcontext.EntityTable.Any(y => y.ID == x.RootID && y.IsOpen)
                    : (DBcontext.EntityTable.Any(y => y.ID == x.RootID && y.IsOpen))
                });
```

It could become cleanier if you hav foreign keys your entity to it self.

I still could not understand your full logic, i just translate what i see in SQL.